# Missing authentication with status code 401 , in Hapijs?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am very new in hapijs, I am doing a demo app with authentication using `hapi-auth-basic`.
but my code,
  (`server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', { validateFunc: validate});` ) the `validate` method is not calling, and the result always giving unauthorized as below:

```
{
  "statusCode": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Missing authentication"
}
```

I want to authorized, can anyone suggest me what to do and where I am doing wrong?

```
'use strict';

const Bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Basic = require('hapi-auth-basic');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000 });

const users = {
    john: {
        username: 'john',
        password: '$2a$10$iqJSHD.BGr0E2IxQwYgJmeP3NvhPrXAeLSaGCj6IR/XU5QtjVu5Tm',   // 'secret'
        name: 'John Doe',
        id: '2133d32a'
    }
};

const validate = function (request, username, password, callback) {
    const user = 'john';
    console.log("1");
    if (!user) {
        return callback(null, false);
    }

    Bcrypt.compare(12345, 12345, (err, isValid) => {
        console.log("2");
        callback(err, isValid, { id: user.id, name: user.name });
    });
};

server.register(Basic, (err) => {
console.log("3");
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', { validateFunc: validate});
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        config: {
            auth: 'simple',
            handler: function (request, reply) {
                console.log("4");
                reply('hello, ' + request.auth.credentials.name);
            }
        }
    });

    server.start((err) => {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log('server running at: ' + server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

Comment: Were u able to solve this...??

Answer (score 1):

**You should create a scheme and then register a strategy like this:**

```
    server.auth.scheme('custom', function (server, options) {
    return {
        authenticate: function (request, reply) {
            const req = request.raw.req;
            const authorization = req.headers.authorization;
            if (!authorization) {
                return reply(Boom.unauthorized(null, 'Custom'));
            }
            return reply.continue({ credentials: { user: 'john' } });
        }
    };
};

 server.auth.strategy('default', 'custom');
```

Comment: This is not answering the ops question though, he is using module hapi-auth-basic

Answer (score 1):

You should send your auth data in Authorization header. Below example in curl, generated by Postman.

```
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:8080 \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic am9objokMmEkMTAkaXFKU0hELkJHcjBFMkl4UXdZZ0ptZVAzTnZoUHJYQWVMU2FHQ2o2SVIvWFU1UXRqVnU1VG0=' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your validate func Bcrypt must be responding with either an error or isValid is false, you must test these return conditions rather than blindly returning the result from function. Also always use return in front of callback to show control flow is leaving function. Use something like hapi's style guide to help find errors earlier.